# How can I read an incoming mail for a rails application in Heroku that uses Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a admin and Customer section in my Rails 2.3.11 application where I need to add the 
reply thread for the actual message  without logging into my application.This is my requirement and my application uses the Heroku as production server and the "SENDGRID" is already activated for sending the messages from my application

Now,I need to know how the send grid works in background and how it reads the incoming mails from my application and how it attaches to the actual Thread

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You mean using the inbound API?

http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/parse-api-2/

Comment: Yes I use the sendgrid API keys for my application

Comment: Kindly help me in replying the message via email using sendgrid in heroku